# Pass the "Your connection is not private" page in Chromium

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, chromium, puppeteer

I encounter this problem when I try to do the testing with Chromium and Jest, but there is a problem that I cannot make the Chromium instance to pass the "Your connection is not private" page and do what I want.

Look like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obZq1.png)

I tried the solution that works on Chrome, by setting like this:

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeP8s.png)

But this setting doesn't make any sense on chromium, for it cannot keep, every time when I try to restart the test, it automatically back to the default setting again.

Appreciate to the help of any kinds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're starting the browser via `puppeteer.launch`, then you can specify HTTPS errors by this configuration:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
```

This should alleviate the issue you're encountering. I found the [docs for this here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.10.0&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, headless: false, timeout: 0 });
```

This worked for me